# Collapse text without using IDs

Tags: javascript, html

I have made the following script to collapse text.

I have a lot of these collapseable boxes on my site. Can I somehow make this without an ID? So you just get an a href tag that is the same everywhere but it collapses the DIV next to it?

```js
  function kadabra(zap) {
   if (document.getElementById) {
   var abra = document.getElementById(zap).style;
    if (abra.display == "block") {
    abra.display = "none";
    } else {
    abra.display= "block";
   }
   return false;
   } else {
   return true;
  }
  }
```

```css
.meerinfobox {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return kadabra('show1');">CLICK4MORE</a> Text Text
<div id="show1" class="meerinfobox">
<pre>
Text text text text text text text
</pre>
</div>

<p>

<a href="#" onclick="return kadabra('show2');">CLICK4MORE</a> Text Text
<div id="show2" class="meerinfobox">
<pre>
Text text text text text text text
</pre>
</div>

<p>

<a href="#" onclick="return kadabra('show3');">CLICK4MORE</a> Text Text
<div id="show3" class="meerinfobox">
<pre>
Text text text text text text text
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be ok to change html structure? Or do you want the solution to fit it exactly?

Comment: @RajeshPaudel you've got that "you can just use the details element" itch too, huh?

Comment: "href tag" isn't a thing. Do you mean an anchor element or an href attribute?

Comment: @WJ496582 did you check our answers?

Answer (score 1):

If the html structure is as I see it, then you can use `nextElementSibling`

[nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling)

So basically your function becomes

```
  function kadabra(el) {
    let abra = el.nextElementSibling;

    if (abra.style.display == "block") {
      abra.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      abra.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
```

and you call it like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="kadabra(this);">CLICK4MORE</a>
```

```js
      function kadabra(el) {
        let abra = el.nextElementSibling;

        if (abra.style.display == "block") {
          abra.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          abra.style.display = "block";
        }
      }
```

```css
     .meerinfobox {
        display: none;
        padding-left: 16px;
      }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section>
    <a href="#" onclick="kadabra(this)">CLICK4MORE</a> Text Text
    <div class="meerinfobox">
      <pre> Text text text text text text text </pre>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <a href="#" onclick="kadabra(this)">CLICK4MORE</a> Text Text
    <div class="meerinfobox">
      <pre>Text text text text text text text </pre>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <a href="#" onclick="kadabra(this)">CLICK4MORE</a> Text Text
    <div class="meerinfobox">
      <pre>Text text text text text text text </pre>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegation for your case.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

container.addEventListener("click", kadabra);

function kadabra(event) {
  const section = event.target.closest("section");
  if (section !== null) {
    section.querySelector("div").classList.toggle("meerinfobox");
  }
}
```

```css
.meerinfobox {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section>
    <p><a href="#">CLICK4MORE</a> Text Text</p>
    <div class="meerinfobox">
      <pre> Text text text text text text text </pre>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p><a href="#">CLICK4MORE</a> Text Text</p>
    <div class="meerinfobox">
      <pre>Text text text text text text text </pre>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p><a href="#">CLICK4MORE</a> Text Text</p>
    <div class="meerinfobox">
      <pre>Text text text text text text text </pre>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```