# Javascript to collapse the first found DIV with classname

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me with this Javascript. This script collapse the next element.

It is not working now because I closed the first DIV in each block.

So the scripts needs to collapse the first "meerinfobox" class it finds.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.meerinfobox {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-tag"><span class="collapsible">&#35;</span> Text 1</div>
<div class="meerinfobox">
Text Text Text
</div>

<div class="color-tag"><span class="collapsible">&#35;</span> Text 2</div>
<div class="meerinfobox">
Text Text Text
</div>

<div class="color-tag"><span class="collapsible">&#35;</span> Text 3</div>
<div class="meerinfobox">
Text Text Text
</div>
```

Comment: `this` in the event handler is the `<span>&#35;</span>` element. Your script will work when you find a way to "move" `this` one element up the DOM to the `<div class="color-tag">`.

Comment: The "toggle" part will only work with the second click, because the `.style` property (unless already modified) will only have the styles that are defined in the markup. The "content" `<div>`s don't have a defined `display` property, hence `content.style.display` will be empty until changed.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your comment but I can't move anything because there's also another script for <div class="color-tag">. The javascript needs be changed somehow.

Comment: You already asked this question before and I answered your question here and I think my solution is a better approach. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68226643/14032355

Comment: Why do you use an answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68226380/collapse-text-without-using-ids) but then change the DOM which causes the problem you describe in this question?

Comment: @ikhvjs Thanks for you comment, I changed the whole thing a bit because I wanted to get rid of the a href tag. Because when I clicked it, the scrollbar went to the top of the page. That was very annoying. Now everything is completely different so I asked again.

Comment: @WJ496582, I think you can add a line ```event.preventDefault()``` in the beginning of ```kadabra``` function in my previous solution. Then it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the `parentNode` to then find the `nextElementSibling` - and you could simplify the javascript like so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span.collapsible').forEach( span => span.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style.display=this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style.display=='block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}));
```

```css
.collapsible {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.meerinfobox {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-tag"><span class="collapsible">&#35;</span> Text 1</div>
<div class="meerinfobox">
Text Text Text
</div>

<div class="color-tag"><span class="collapsible">&#35;</span> Text 2</div>
<div class="meerinfobox">
Text Text Text
</div>

<div class="color-tag"><span class="collapsible">&#35;</span> Text 3</div>
<div class="meerinfobox">
Text Text Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). The handler is assigned on the document level. The `handle` function checks if the element click occured somewhere within a `div.color-tag` and if so, toggles the `visible` css class for its' next sibling (that being `div.meerinfobox`).

[See also](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gv2m6a?file=index.js)

```js
document.addEventListener('click', handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const collapsible = evt.target.closest(".color-tag");
  if (collapsible) {
    return collapsible.nextElementSibling
      .classList.toggle("visible");
  }
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.meerinfobox {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.meerinfobox.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-tag"><span class="collapsible">&#35;</span> Text 1</div>
<div class="meerinfobox">
Text Text Text
</div>

<div class="color-tag"><span class="collapsible">&#35;</span> Text 2</div>
<div class="meerinfobox">
Text Text Text
</div>

<div class="color-tag"><span class="collapsible">&#35;</span> Text 3</div>
<div class="meerinfobox">
Text Text Text
</div>
```